# Scaling a rectangular shape

Tags: modeling

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNbAmJ3eubo) tutorial and between 16:00 and 20:00 min this part with the crease is modelled. [image]

Now every time he extrudes some part of the mesh like below he says he has to scale the other axis to get it even on the other axis. I don't understand this.

[image]

when I take this "matcap" view the right part looks a bit strange is not it ?

[image]

here is my blend file. If someone would like to take a look if I have done this part of the modelling ok it is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: now the link works and I also uploaded a better version of my blend file

Comment: I think he means the X axis when he says "the other axis" (first he scales the total rectangular shape then just the "X" axis). Because he is working with a rectangular shape, normal scaling will have a bigger influence on the "Z" scaling then the "X". In contrast to scaling on an even square, both "Z" and "X" wil scale even. To adjust this, he scales some more on the "X" Axis independently.

Comment: would you mind having a look at my file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a peek.

You are doing it quite well. But you should scale some more on just the X Axis through this part of the tutorial. (16:00 - 20:00)

At 19:28 he says exactly what I just said as a comment. That for a rectangular shape it's not gonna scale equally (for the X and Z in this situation).

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: ok I will try. And why is this right part of my "matcap" view dark ?

Comment: Then you need to recalculate the normals. In edit mode sellect all the vertices "A". There is a tab on the left called "Shading/UV's" in there you can find the "Recalculate" button.

Comment: you are right, recalculating the normals did work